# g95 graphics library

Tags: fortran

MS Fortran Powerstation, then Compaq's, then someone elses and now Intel's compilers used to come with a sweet graphics library that enabled you to plot directly on screen with *MoveTo* and *LineTo*.

Anyways, ... a friend of mine is jumping from FPS4 to something newer nowadays, and since it's his private compiler, he hasn't got the means to buy a new version from Intel.

***Do any other compilers (for example g95) come with similar libraries?***

Answer (score 1):

While a little more complicated, I sometimes have programs write postscript files directly.  The syntax is not difficult, and can be quite useful for plotting data.

Comment: In this case, it's for drawing hpgl files. But, anyways, I need something of an alternative since it's quite a few programs he will have to change otherwise. The old library also was very useful for directly drawing on screen (some specific plotting for cfd, which usually aren't that common in graphics libraries).

Answer (score 1):

Both dislin and plplot are graphic libraries that have both Fortran interfaces and numerous output formats.    Both can be free.   plplot is open source, but I found it difficult to install from their distribution; OK from MacPorts.   Maybe one of these will meet the need.   They could be used with any Fortran compiler, such as g95 or gfortran.

Comment: Well aware of them (been using dislin for a very long time now) But I'm not looking for a "general" graphics library, but one that will enable me to replace the old one as painlessly as possible. I'm not aware dislin has anything like lineto/moveto. Would be glad to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Btw, MoveTo places the position to a certain pixel coordinate, and LineTo draws a line from that position to a new one (given).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new, but very promissing, library of gtk bindings for Fortran. https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki You should be probably interested in the Cairo part.

Comment: Arguably this doesn't answer the (now potentially regarded as off-topic) question of being a compiler with a bundled graphics library. Instead it's a separate library which can be used (presumably) with any compiler if so built.